# How to convert properly from NSData to NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I'm getting weird NSString value after performing a conversion. For example, I have one byte with value 2 (00000010) that is stored in response. I tried both NSString initWithData and initWithBytes  but both return weird symbol (upside down question mark). Here's my code:

```
NSString *command1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *command2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[response bytes] length:[response length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"command1: %@", command1);
NSLog(@"command2: %@", command2);
```

Also tried NSUTF8StringEncoding but NSASCIIStringEncoding is correct one because data comes encoded one byte per symbol.

Comment: What do you expect? The byte with value '2' is STX, or start of text. What do you want to come from this byte?

Comment: What are you expecting to get? All the characters in ascii table up to 32 (space) are considered control characters which don't have a decent representation.

Comment: The response that comes are numbers encoded to bytes. So for example, I need to parse 2 from 00000010.

Comment: @Centurion so it's a simple binary conversion? That is easy enough, let me write something up.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm getting packet of bytes from socket. 1 byte contains number, second 4 bytes contains response size (also number), left bytes contain characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am reading, this is what you want:

```
NSString *stringWithContentsOfBinaryData(NSData *data)
{
    NSMutableString *output;

    int len = [data length];
    uint8_t *bytes = [data bytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        [output appendFormat:@"%i", bytes[i]];
    } 

    return output;
}
```

It just simply converts each byte to it's integer representation and concatenates that into a string.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is not necessarily the right encoding.  ASCII only defines characters between `0x00` and `0x7F`.  If response is an HTTP response, and the encoding is not specified in the HTTP `Content-Type` header, the default is ISO-8859-1 for which you should use `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`

And it doesn't matter what encoding you use:  control characters (`0x00` - `0x1F`) aren't necessarily printable.